# How to add background-color in a section part?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Is there any other way to add background color in section tag? Except using `body {background-color: blue;}`, what is are other ways to add background color into section?

I am trying to add the section background color like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
        <style>
            #ABC {
                background-color: blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="ABC">
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

There is no color showing on my browser.

Comment: Not showing because `#ABC` does not contains any content.

Comment: It's because there is no content in your section. Try adding `height: 100px` then you can see the background color.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its because `#ABC` does not have any content or does not have a height!

See below what happened when I have set a height to it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing</title>

    <style>

    #ABC {
      background-color: blue;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }

    body{
      background: grey;
      margin: 0;
    } 

    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

<section id="ABC">


</section>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to add background-color to the whole background, add it to the "body"-tag. If not, this answer is correct.

Comment: @R3y see how I applied a color to the whole page

Comment: Which mean there is no way to add background color to the whole background on the section part? Except using body {background-color: blue;}?

Comment: possible... I stretched out `section` to fill the body and see the result.

Answer (score 1):

`<section>` element is an grouping container. In your example there is no content and hence it's not visible (*I have added red color border to highlight the* `<section>`).

**Highlighting the `<section>`:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Testing</title>
  <style>
    #ABC {
      background-color: blue;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="ABC">

  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Try adding `height` or content to your `<section>` for the background-color to be visible.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Testing</title>
  <style>
    #ABC {
      background-color: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="ABC">
    Some text here
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe they should try a little more color using gradient.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Testing</title>
  <style>
    #ABC {
      background-image: linear-gradient(45deg,rgb(218,34,255) 30%,#9733ee 90%);
padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 1em 0;
color: #fff;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="ABC">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```